# Is there a 'clean' way to omit a static type declaration?

Tags: java

So consider a function like this:

```
public void setTemperature(double newTemperatureValue, TemperatureUnit unit)
```

where TemperatureUnit is defined as:

```
public enum TemperatureUnit {celcius, kelvin, fahrenheit}
```

I would ideally like to get to is this:

```
setTemperature(23, celcius);
```

So ultimately I would like to omit the 'TemperatureUnit.' part that would normally precede the value of the enum, since in this way the function reads more like as if it was regular text.

Now I can of course do a static import to accomplish this, but I wonder if there are alternatives to that, hopefully while also keeping things clean. I have heard of people using an interface that declares them, but which is also considered bad practice.

Any suggestions?

Comment: He already mentioned static imports.

Comment: I'd stick with the TemperatureUnit part. After all, what's celcius, someone may ask? It's a temperature unit... I honestly think it's more readable that way. Otherwise you could use your TemperatureUnit vals as byte values, declared as finals within your class...

Comment: @Vicente: You should already know what Celcius is.

Comment: @DeadMG not really. Although I suppose it's Celsius, with s. Such typo is far more intuitive if we're talking about, well, `TemperatureUnit`s .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you've listed all 3 technical possibilities. Personally, I'd favor using the full name of the enum class but rename it to produce more natural sounding code:

```
public enum Degrees{CELSIUS, KELVIN, FAHRENHEIT}
```

Comment: I actually like that a lot. It is both a solution and adds an additional description to the function call :)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility, if your intent is just to make your code less verbose, is to provide an overload that takes a character or string, something like:

```
setTemp (23, "C");
```

although I would just bite the bullet and use the qualified names - this suggestion "damages" the integrity of the type system in my opinion, and should probably be avoided.

Comment: A string is possible, but it also means you have to create a new string object just for the sake of telling the function what to do. A char is possible, as it is basically an int, but is then again not very descriptive. Hence my preference for the use of enums.

Comment: This isn't wrong enough for me to downvote, but I strongly recommend against it. You'll not have to use the function for a few months, and when one day you do, you'll have to search through your code to remember if it was "C" or "c" or "Celsius" or "CELSIUS" or whether you can also specify Kelvin or what.

Comment: That's why I gave it as a possibility but advised against it. In either case, tou'd still have to remember whether it were CELSIUS or CELS or C even as an enumerated type :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I just wanted the emphasize the "advised against it" part. :) As for the enum name, any half-decent IDE will give you autocomplete options for it, and if you're working in vim/emacs, at least you have a single place to look -- and a compilation error if you get it wrong. If the String approach is complemented with something like `String getTempUnits()`, it's much more of a hassle (and it's more fragile) to make sure that all of your `set` call sites agree with all of your `get` call sites about what the domain is. An enum defines that domain.